# Emacs - select between parens

Tags: emacs, elisp, parentheses

I have the following defun's in my .emacs.d:

```
;;; http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching
(defun goto-match-paren (arg)
  "Go to the matching  if on (){}[], similar to vi style of % "
  (interactive "p")
  ;; first, check for "outside of bracket" positions expected by forward-sexp, etc.
  (cond ((looking-at "[\[\(\{]") (forward-sexp))
        ((looking-back "[\]\)\}]" 1) (backward-sexp))
        ;; now, try to succeed from inside of a bracket
        ((looking-at "[\]\)\}]") (forward-char) (backward-sexp))
        ((looking-back "[\[\(\{]" 1) (backward-char) (forward-sexp))
        (t nil)))

(defun select-in-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-match-paren 1)
  (set-mark (point)))
```

I originally just had the first function. Then I added the second, which I intended to select an entire s-expression. Now, I have one of these bound to M-[, and the other to M-]. When I go to a paren and hit the "goto" key, it does what I want - jumps to the other one. If I hit the "select" key after that... it does the same thing, without marking the region, and hitting it repeatedly after that makes it jump between parens. But if I do "goto" after that, it *does* mark the region, and hitting it repeatedly jumps back and unmarks it.

So basically I have the functions I wanted... but reversed, and I don't know why. Can someone explain what's going on here, and maybe offer a solution?

Comment: Can you clarify this better - maybe with an example: "But what happens is that "select" goes to the matching paren, and if I then do "goto", that one selects everything. So basically I have the functions I wanted... but reversed, and I don't know why. Can someone explain what's going on here, and maybe offer a solution?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe set-mark before moving the point?

```
(defun select-in-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark (point))
  (goto-match-paren 1))
```

Comment: not bad! I'm debating whether I want it to also unmark if the s-exp is already marked (something like a test of mark-active, then save-excursion, find if the mark is at the other paren?). but I think this is fine.

Comment: I believe it would be more "correct" to use `push-mark` instead of `set-mark`. Besides the correctness of this if you one day want to share your code, it will be easier for you to have the old mark in the mark-ring and add some logic based on that...

Comment: except push-mark doesn't do what I want: mark everything between the parens.

Comment: `push-mark` is supposed to push a new mark in the mark-ring positioned at the cursor's position. After calling push-mark the active mark is at the cursor position, only if you want to return to your previous mark all you have to do is pop the mark ring. I hope i understood your comment correctly.

Comment: Well, I'm not really interested in getting back to the previous mark, just want a quick way to mark a sexp.